# Power out on just one section of the house

Tags: electrical

I have been having trouble with one line in my house. We have had power going out in just one line in my house intermittently.   An electrician has changed the outlets and we exchanged the circuit breaker but it is still happening.   Any suggestions?

Comment: Did s/he use backstabs on the receptacles?

Comment: No.  My electrician wh

Comment: My electrician (a friend who is helping me) started what he thought was the first outlet on the line we were having trouble with and fixed two that were backstabbed and then looked at the next two outlets.  He wanted to see where in the line is causing the short so we started at what we thought was the beginning and hoped that would fix it.   He also replaced the circuit breaker with a spare I had justvin case that was the problem.   He can't figure out what else to do or to test.

Comment: You say one line in the house ? One Circuit ? or one line as in a Neutral, Hot ?? When you say power going out, devices on that 'line' do not work  (and I am assuming you mean circuit because you mention changing a breaker) OR does the circuit breaker trip and you have to reset it? Hots are one thing but sometimes a crafty Neutral connection might have been made, I would place one of those cheap prong testers in the socket where it can show if neutral/hot is functioning, so when it goes out I could take note of what is wrong. Anything besides receptacles on the circuit, what devices as well?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question, you describe a common issue. When troubleshooting electrical circuits, remember electricity must have a complete path back to its source. This means you not only need a path to the load but a path returning to the source from whence it came. A connection in the neutral path could be loose.

You are doing well not to ignore this intermittent problem as it points to a probable loose connection somewhere on either side of the path. Loose connections quickly build up heat and can very easily start a fire.

Since the entire circuit is having trouble, do not forget to check for loose connections at the panel, especially at the neutral bar, and of course the breaker. Try wiggling the wires while you have a multimeter checking voltage. If the voltage suddenly drops you may have just found your loose wire. Trim, restrip, and reconnect.

Next, pay close attention to the connections at each outlet. Look for obvious signs of heat (melted insulation on conductors, smoke residue in the box), but also for anything that may not be making a good connection. Wiggle the conductors on the screw terminals. If they move around or slip on the screw, voila! Loose connection. Another culprit is insulation that is a little too long and is actually tucked under a screw, preventing a good metal to metal contact between wire and device. Over time, with usage and vibration, the screw may loosen enough to create the intermittent problem you are having. Try tugging on each conductor individually in each wire nut. There could be a loose wire that falls right out of its splice, and bingo! there you are. If you see any of the aforementioned, trim (if possible), restrip and reconnect properly. Sometimes it is better to start fresh with a new tip of conductor that isn't going to break from past stresses. I like about 3/4" of bare conductor laid evenly in wire nut splices or with a nice candy-cane shape for screw terminal connections. Also, be sure to test each spliced connection by tugging on the individual wires to be sure you've got a tight splice. With the screw terminals, think of the candy cane's short end as the pointer and make it point in a clockwise direction going around the screw.

While you are searching for loose connections in the outlet boxes, you can have the circuit turned off for safety; however, another method I've seen involves having the circuit on: Plug in a lamp or something that will indicate when you've got power. Take a piece of wood or something non-conductive and go around poking and prodding into the open boxes and their wiring. If the light suddenly goes on (or off as the case may be) your issue is probably in the box at hand.

Don't forget light switch boxes, which may have been used as a junction box for your circuit and which get vibration daily. One last place to look for loose connections, a junction box in an attic or basement, although that would probably be the least likely place as it wouldn't get much traffic.

These are the best recommendations I can think of, although your electrician friend may have already done them all. Hope you find the issue, Nancy, these things can be quite irritating!

Answer (score 0):

Intermitten problems are the hardest to troubleshoot, but you mentioned you have had an electrician out to repair the problem. This may not be the answer you are looking for but he is responsible for repairing your problem. If he tried and failed, you need to contact that contractor and tell him that you paid for the repair and that it still isn't fixed. Any reputatble contractor will return and make the aporpriate repairs.

Comment: He is a friend who is an electrician and is doing me a favour.

Answer (score 0):

Did ou check the voltage at the main breaker? Sounds like one leg of you service is going bad and it is likely to be a a direct bury underground service im guessing. A rock will cut the insulation around the wire , let water to come in contact with the wire, causing the wire to corrode. When the wire is corrode to the point that when water is in contact with the corrosion  it will cause your electric to go out on the circuit.when it arcs and or dryies out the corrosion your electric will come back on. Eventually the wire will corrode and arc enough that leg of your service will become de-energized.